# App Modularisation with SPM; Modules vs Local Dependencies

Tags: ios, architecture, swift-package-manager

I currently have an app that's modularised with cocoapods, however I'm looking into migrating over to swift package manager instead.

My app has multiple modules, these modules depend on other modules. All modules ultimately depend on the core module.

When looking into SPM i've noticed that each package can have multiple targets and targets themselves can be defined as modules. These modules can then depend on other modules all within the same package. Each module would be a different folder on the root of the source directory. E.G.

```
targets: [
        .target(
          name: "Core",
          dependencies: []),
        .target(
            name: "FeatureOne",
            dependencies: ["Core"]),
        .target(
            name: "FeatureTwo",
            dependencies: ["FeatureOne"]),
    ]
```

This seems to be one way of doing modularisation.
However it seems we can also do it with multiple packages added as local dependencies. So instead of having one package with modules, we could have multiple local package dependencies. Then each of these package dependencies could then have their own set of modules, additionally each of these packages could then depend on other packages. E.G.

```
dependencies: [
      .package(path: "../FeatureOne")
      .package(path: "../FeatureTwo")
      .package(path: "../Core")
    ],
```

Are there any particular advantages to doing it one way or the other? Or should we be combining these two methods by using dependencies and modules at the same time?
For example, in the modules case I can imagine that every time one of the dependent modules changes, we would have to recompile the parent module too. However in the second example that wouldn't necessarily be true.